# Why do high voltage relays stop at 70kV?

Tags: relay, high-voltage

My project needs high voltage SPST relays. The voltage involved is 120kV and maximum current is 0.25mA.

Gigavac makes nice sealed contact relays like this, but only seem to go to 70kV rating, sadly.

Is there any physical/engineering reason to stop at 70kV? Is it possible to make them at a higher voltage? And how would I go about getting them, in general terms? I don't need any manufacturer names, just some input about the process if any experienced engineer were faced with such a need.

For the sake of answers, assume that I can't redesign the system not to use such a relay.

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to sales/applications engineers at companies that make such relays. It is such a small field of applications that most purchases require actually talking to people. Really. Majority of such products start by a customer talking to an engineer at the company, going over options, and it ending with a custom-made product. If the company deems it worth adding to the catalog, they'll do so then :)

Most such components were designed for a customer before they ended up in the catalog. Gigavac didn't just decide one day "let's make 70kV relays". A customer had a need for them, and they made them.

As a very, very loose rule of thumb or order-of-magnitude planning aid, budget for such projects is approximated by replacing Volts with USDs/Euros/GBPs.

Comment: Well for some reason my original question was modified (by yourself?). The original title made it clear (at least I thought so) that I was looking for such suppliers. I did not want to know 'why do high voltage relays stop at 70kv'. I don't know that they do. I'm not convinced that this title is going to get me any answers now :(. I get that its a relatively niche field, thats why I was looking for some supplier names I could talk to or even find someone who has used relays at these voltages that they could recommend.